# Basis of neighbourhoods in a profinite group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

The Krull topology in a Galois group $G$ of a Galois extension $L/K$ is defined taking $\sigma\:G(L/M)$, where $M/K$ varies through the Galois finite subextensions of $L/K$, as a fundamental system of neighbourhoods of $\sigma\in G$. This turns G into a profinite group.

Conversely, given a profinite group $G$, (without assuming that it is a Galois group), is there an elementary argument showing that we have for each point a fundamental system of neighbourhoods consisting of cosets in a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A profinite group *G* is by definition an inverse limit of finite groups $G_i$. If the $G_i$ 's are endowed with the discrete topology, *G* is naturally a compact and totally disconnected topological group. The converse is true, from which it follows that such a *G* admits a basis of neighbourhoods of $1$ consisting of open normal subgroups *U*, and *G* is isomorphic to the inverse limit of the quotients *G/U*. You'll find all this explained in detail in the chapter "Profinite Groups" of Cassels-Fröhlich's book "Algebraic Number Theory". Does this answer your question ?